# How Not To Execute Data If imgProductx Is NULL In The Database

Tags: php, sql-server, if-statement

I have to following php code where I want to execute the image function if there is an image to show. Which means If the image field is empty/NULL I dont want to show the image, because it will give an error saying 'no image found'.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<div>
   <?php if (!empty($datas[0]['imgProduct1'])){ ?>
         <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct1']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product1" />
   <?php } ?>
</div>
<div>
   <?php if (!empty($datas[0]['imgProduct2'])){ ?>
         <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct2']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product2" />
   <?php } ?>
</div>
<div>
   <?php if (!empty($datas[0]['imgProduct3'])){ ?>
         <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct3']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product3" />
   <?php } ?>
</div>
<div>
   <?php if (!empty($datas[0]['imgProduct4'])){ ?>
         <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct4']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product4" />
   <?php } ?>
</div>

(Goes till imgProduct8)
```

In the Database image, I have my picture data ready. In the last line you see imgProduct1 filled, imgProduct2 filled, imgProduct3 filled. After that imgProduct4 is NULL, so I dont want to execute the image function for that matter.

Database image:

[image: 1]]

In Result from the database picture, you see the result I am getting. So again imgProduct1, imgProduct2 and imgProduct3 are filled with a link, imgProduct4, imgProduct5 etc are not. So I dont want to show the image, thats not there.

Result from database:

[image: 2]]

The result I am getting now is 3 pictures in my slide show and after that just blank pictures. So he is still think there are more pictures to show.

my whole code:

```
<?php

require('../php/connection.php');
$product = $_GET['product'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE strProductNaam='$product'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);


if( $result === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datas[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($datas);
echo '</pre>';

sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Home Gym</title>

    <?php
        include('../structure/effects.php');
    ?>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <?php
        include('../structure/header.php');
    ?>
    <!-- /Header -->



    <!-- Main -->
    <main>

<br>
        <!-- Product Section -->      
<section class="single-product">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                    <div class="site-slider">
                        <div class="slider-one">
                            <div>
                                <?php if (!empty($datas[0]['imgProduct1'])){ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct1']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product1" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <?php if (!empty($datas[0]['imgProduct2'])){ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct2']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product2" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <?php if (!empty($datas[0]['imgProduct3'])){ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct3']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product3" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <?php if (($datas[0]['imgProduct4']) !== NULL){ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct4']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product4" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <?php if (($datas[0]['imgProduct4']) !== NULL){ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct5']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product5" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <?php if (($datas[0]['imgProduct4']) !== NULL){ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct6']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product6" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <?php if (($datas[0]['imgProduct4']) !== NULL){ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct7']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product7" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <?php if (($datas[0]['imgProduct4']) !== NULL){ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct8']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product8" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider-button">
                            <span class="prev position-top"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
                            <span class="next position-top right-0"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <p class="new-arrival text-center">NEW</p>
                <div class="product-bottom">
                <p><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                </p>
                <p><h3><?php echo ($datas[0]['strProductNaam']); ?></h3></p>
                <p class="price"><h5><s>€<?php echo ($datas[0]['intPrijs']); ?></s>  <b><span class="make_red">€<?php echo ($datas[0]['strSalePrijs']); ?></span> </b></h5></p>
                <p><b>Availability: </b>In Stock</p>   
                </div>
                <div class="positive">
                <p><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo ($datas[0]['strPlusPunt1']); ?></p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo ($datas[0]['strPlusPunt2']); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="negative">

                </div>

                <label>Quantity: </label>
                <input class="text-center" type="text" value="1"></input>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>

                <table class="content-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Product Specifications</th>
                        <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Type</td>
                        <td><?php echo ($datas[0]['strSpecSoort']); ?></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active-row">
                        <td>Guarantee</td>
                        <td><?php echo ($datas[0]['strSpecGarantie']); ?></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Material</td>
                        <td><?php echo ($datas[0]['strSpecMateriaal']); ?></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active-row">
                        <td>Weight</td>
                        <td><?php echo ($datas[0]['strGewicht']); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>


        <!-- /Product Section -->


        <!-- Product Description -->
<section class="product-description">
    <div class="container">
        <h6>Product Description</h6>
        <p><?php echo ($datas[0]['strBeschrijving']); ?></p>
    </div>
</section>
        <!-- /Product Descriptionn -->
<br>    
        <hr class="hr">

        <!-- On Sale Product -->
        <?php
        include('../product-sale.php');
        ?>
        <!-- /On Sale Product -->

    </main>
    <!-- /Main -->


    <!-- Footer -->
    <?php
    include('../structure/footer.php');
    ?>
    <!-- /Footer -->

    <!-- Script: Bootstrap CDN, JS -->
    <?php
    include('../structure/script.php');
    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try updating the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE image_column != NULL
```

Hope so it might help you. It would be better if you provide the whole code...

Comment: my whole code would be 200 lines, but I will add it for you. @Unicas

Comment: ok so you might use this method like "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE strProductNaam='$product' and picture != null

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
<?php if (!empty($datas[0]['imgProduct1'])){ ?>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="<?php echo ($datas[0]['imgProduct1']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product1" />
                                    </div>
                            <?php } ?>
```

The div had to be inside of the if function. That's why a white screen popped up.